# AppleScript and InDesign CS6: minimum document size error?

Tags: applescript, adobe-indesign

Let's do an experiment. Using InDesign CS6, make a new document that is 1" x 1". No problem here, right?

Now run this script:

```
tell application "Adobe InDesign CS6"
    set page width of document preferences of active document to 1
end tell
```

Should be easy, right? You're just telling InDesign to set the document size to a size it *already has*.

```
error "Adobe InDesign CS6 got an error: Data is out of range." number 30481
```

Just what in the blazes is going on here? I'm able to get applescript to set the page size down to 1.0139 inches -- but no smaller. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Why would the accepted value be higher than what InDesign actually allows for its document size? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: No problem in CS5: `set page width of document preferences of active document to "1 pt"` Maybe your values for document bleed keeps you away from changing the document's width?

Comment: My bleed didn't affect the results, no matter what I set it to.

Comment: This has been noticed before; for small values the New Document dialog may complain about the margins, *even though* they are set to 0 (!) and a larger document can be sized much smaller (!!). It is not a particular AppleScript problem. It's up to Adobe to fix this.